# WSO2IS 5.10 custom JWT token issuer not listed in Service Provider configuration

Tags: jwt, wso2, token, wso2-identity-server

in **WSO2IS 5.7** I used to utilize a custom JWT token issuer by deploying its jar file into `wso2is_home/repository/components/lib`, then changing the `OAuth` section in `identity.xml` file at the `IdentityOAuthTokenGenerator` element with my custom token issuer's class:

```
<OAuth>
  ...
  <!--<IdentityOAuthTokenGenerator>org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.JWTTokenIssuer</IdentityOAuthTokenGenerator>-->
  <IdentityOAuthTokenGenerator>it.smartcity.wso2.jwt_generator.CustomTokenIssuer</IdentityOAuthTokenGenerator>
  ...
</OAuth>
```

restarting the server. Then I was able to see it in the Service Provider configuration:

[image]

With **WSO2IS 5.10**, besides putting the jar in the `components/lib` folder, I edited only the `deployment.toml` file, adding the following:

```
[oauth.extensions]
token_generator = "it.smartcity.wso2.jwt_generator.CustomTokenIssuer"
```

as described here https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/extension-points-for-oauth/#oauth-token-generator but it just doesn't work.

I can't see my token issuer in the Service Provider screen.

Is there anything else I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom token issuers in the following way in 5.10.0 instead of token_generator.

```
[[oauth.extensions.token_types]]
name = "CustomTokenIssuer"
issuer = "it.smartcity.wso2.jwt_generator.CustomTokenIssuer"
persist_access_token_alias = true
```

Ref: https://github.com/wso2/docs-is/issues/1140

Comment: So looks like the section `[oauth.extensions] token_generator` is not needed  at all. Then I ask myself what is needed for...